# How to make button in one class affect text area in another?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextarea

Please help me to understand how this works. I'm having difficulties to understand how, for example, `JButton` in one class can alter text in `JTextArea` that is in another class of a same package. I've made a simple app just to ask a question here, I need this for a bigger school project where I need to implement this to work with multiple classes.

When I put everything in the same class it works but I need it in separate classes.

Here is the simple code.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Button extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;
    private Panel panel;

    public Button() {
        button = new JButton("BUTTON");
        panel = new Panel();
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
                String input = clicked.getText();
                panel.setTextArea(input);
                //System.out.println(input);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public Panel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    void setTextArea(String text) {
        this.textArea.setText(text);
    }
}

public class Java extends JFrame {

    private Button dugme;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Panel panel;

    public Java() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        dugme = new Button();
        panel = new Panel();
        //super("test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(dugme, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Java app = new Java();
    }
}
```

I want action listener to alter the text in the panel, sys-out works so the listener listens the button but I can't make it to alter the text in text area.

Comment: the `panel` in your `Button` class is not the same instance as the one you use in `Java` class

Comment: Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! Most IDEs have a keyboard shortcut specifically for formatting code.

Comment: @AndrewThompson for my school project i have to make an app with 5+ classes, i've planned to create a calculator where number buttons would be in one class display would be in another and operation buttons would be in a different class, this program i've made simply to understand how to force classes to communicate

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. And yes, that's what I would've guessed. BTW - much thanks for posting 3 classes that (almost - sans imports and one too many public classes) made a [mcve], but please do class naming a little different. E.G. `Button` is not a button, but a `ButtonContainer`. `Panel` is not a panel, but a `TextContainer`. Those two names are also existing classes in the AWT package, which creates confusion for the reader. `Java` would better be named `CrossClassAccessProblem` (or something similar..). Note that all three are longer than the names seen above, but one purpose of ..

Comment: .. high level languages is to be easy to read & understand. Using descriptive (possibly long) names aids in understanding.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for the tips about class names, definitely will remember that, tho the example i shared was not intended to be shared when i gave the names wasn't thinking about it when i shared it here, i understand now that it made it difficult to figure out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already mentioned by @XtremeBaumer you have two different instances of `Panel` class. You need to remove the secode one.

```
public class Button extends JPanel {
    private JButton button;
    private Panel panel;
    public Button(Panel panel) { // we need already created instance of panel here.
        this.panel = panel;
        button = new JButton("BUTTON");
        // panel = new Panel(); <-- this line must be deleted.
        // ...
    }
}
public class Java extends JFrame {
    private Button dugme;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Panel panel;
    public Java(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new Panel();
        dugme = new Button(panel);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Please also replace the line

```
add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

by

```
add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

This allows you to get the scrool bars when text goes larger than the text ara size.

Here is your reworked example

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

class Button extends JPanel {

    private JButton button;
    private Panel panel;

    public Button(Panel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
        button = new JButton("BUTTON");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JButton clicked = (JButton) e.getSource();
                String input = clicked.getText();
                panel.setTextArea(input);
                //System.out.println(input);
            }
        });
    }
}

class Panel extends JPanel {

    private JTextArea textArea;

    public Panel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        textArea = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JTextArea getTextArea() {
        return textArea;
    }

    void setTextArea(String text) {
        this.textArea.setText(text);
    }
}

public class Java extends JFrame {

    private Button dugme;
    private JFrame frame;
    private Panel panel;

    public Java() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        panel = new Panel();
        dugme = new Button(panel);
        //super("test");
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setTitle("test");
        frame.setSize(300, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.add(dugme, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Java app = new Java();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, Sergiy, but I just had to 'break' your nice round figure of 8,000 rep. to add an up vote.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy im aware of JScrollPane but this text area should represent calculator display and was intentionally left without scrolling. After fixing the code the action listener still wont change text on the panel

Comment: @Draza I've tested it again. All works fine for me. After clicking the button, I get the text in the text area. Probably you've forget to remove the line `panel = new Panel();` in the class Button?

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy It works now for me too, i havent forgot to remove line you've mentioned but in Java file button constructor was in line before panel constructor `panel = new Panel();
        dugme = new Button(panel);` when i swapped those lines in code it worked... Thanks again Sergiy, i have one problem still, i dont understand how it works now, why we made `public Button(Panel panel) {
        this.panel = panel; //.... }` would really appreciate if you can clear things for me